# Whats the probability of given two-dice experiment?

Tags: probability

In given two dice experiment, Red and Green.

I am told that after the roll, ONE of the dice has '6'. It is not told which dice is 6. Then I am asked to choose a number. What is the probability that I choose the correct pattern? e.g. I choose 3.

(a). So the Successful answer can be (3,6) or (6,3)

Is the probability of success following?

P(Success) = P[(6,3) or (3,6)] = 1/6 + 1/6 = 2/6 ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the correct number"?

Comment: pardon. I mean by the correct number that The Number I called.

Comment: What number do you choose also matters.  If I am understanding the problem correctly, you will have a lower chance of success if you choose $6$ than if you choose any of the others.

Comment: Well, there are $11$ equally probable dice roll that have the property that at least one of the two dice shows a $6$.  Thus if you choose $6$, the answer is $\frac 1{11}$.  If you choose anything else, it is $\frac 2{11}$.  But I am not sure I have understood your question.

Comment: @lulu That looks like an answer.  Make it so.

Comment: @GrahamKemp  But...I have a strong feeling that this is not the question the OP wanted answered.  These sort of problems depend too much on the exact process involved.

Answer (score 0):

If at least one of the dice is a six, then there are eleven equally possible outcomes.   Red is 6 and Green is any other number, or Red is any other number and Green is 6, or both Red and Green are 6. $$\mathcal E=\{6\}{\times}\{1,2,3,4,5\}\cup \{1,2,3,4,5\}{\times} \{6\}\cup\{(6,6)\}$$

Evaluating the probobabilities of $\mathsf P(\omega\in\{(3,6),(6,3)\}\mid\omega\in \mathcal E)$ et cetera, and $\mathsf P(\omega\in\{(6,6)\}\mid\omega\in\mathcal E)$ , should now be obvious.

However, you ask: what is the probability you choose the correct number?  Interpeting this as: if you select $X$ from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ at random (unbiased), what is the probability that one of the dice show $X$ when given one of the die shows 6?

$$\mathsf P(\omega\in\{(X,6),(6,X)\}\mid\omega\in \mathcal E) = {\sum_{x=1}^5 \mathsf P(X=x)\mathsf P(\omega\in\{(x,6),(6,x)\}\mid\omega\in\mathcal E)\\+\mathsf P(X=6)\mathsf P(\omega\in\{(6,6)\}\mid\omega\in\mathcal E)}$$